# When do we need to upgrade to new version Xcode (.i.e Xcode 11)?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

When do we need to upgrade XCode to newer version? Is it ok if we use older version (.i.e build IPA for iOS 13.1 with XCode 10 or even XCode 9)
(to debug with newer iPhone, iPad is one reason :D)

Comment: It's required to build iOS 13 SDK in April 2020: https://www.macrumors.com/2019/09/10/apple-apps-ios-13-sdk-april-2020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can develop/build/release your app to be compatible with iOS 13 on older Xcode, you cannot add new features that are present in XCode 11 such as dark mode, `Sign in with Apple`, new simulators (yes, there is a way to add iOS 13 simulators into older XCode but I wouldn't recommend doing it), new code signing, Swift UI and many more. 
Also - `Sign in with Apple` is going to be required for a lot of apps soon so that's a huge push into the new XCode.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to work with older iOS versions, but at some point you won't be able to run an application for the latest iOS releases (for example iOS13) and also you won't be able to use SwiftUI framework for developing.

Of course you won't have access to new features of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you developing on older version of Xcode then you can not use `dark/light` mode feature on your app, also in future it's compulsory to build/upload app using latest Xcode version for latest iOS support.